# Testing json.Marshal(myType) with typed parameter

Tags: go, testing

I have this method

```
func getRequestBody(object MyType ) ([]byte, error) {
    if object == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }

    requestBody, err := json.Marshal(object)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("unable to marshal the request body to json")
    }
    return requestBody, nil
}
```

And I'm trying to test the function like this:

```
    t.Run("errorMarshaling", func(t *testing.T) {

        body, err := getRequestBody([some object of MyType to do the marshal fail])

        assert.Nil(t, body)
        assert.Equal(t, err.Error(), "unable to marshal the request body to json")
    })
```

Is there any way to do it without changing the function attribute type?

Comment: How can I change the function's body?  Which is the best approach?  Thanks @mkopriva!

Comment: What's the definition of `MyType`? Is it an empty-interface type? If not then you *should* change the function's parameter type to an empty-interface type, named or unnamed, it's up to you. And in Go 1.18 you can use `any` as an alternative/alias. If you can't then you'll have to change the function's body by adding a "is_test" flag that's set to true during test setup and then in the function you check for that an if true you overwrite the argument passed to json.Marshal. The former option is far better than the latter.

Comment: Understood!  Thanks so much @mkopriva

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/PGAmW57l-2m

Answer (score 2):

json.marshall will only throw an error in specific circumstances listed in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal):

> Channel, complex, and function values cannot be encoded in JSON.
> Attempting to encode such a value causes Marshal to return an
> UnsupportedTypeError.
>
> JSON cannot represent cyclic data structures and Marshal does not
> handle them. Passing cyclic structures to Marshal will result in an
> error.

If the underlying object doesn't have the ability to meet one of these criteria, I don't think you'll be able to get it to fail in your test.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I changed my function parameter

```
type myTypeBody interface{}

func getRequestBody(object myTypeBody ) ([]byte, error) {
    if object == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }

    requestBody, err := json.Marshal(object)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("unable to marshal the request body to json")
    }
    return requestBody, nil
}
```

And the test

```
t.Run("errorMarshaling", func(t *testing.T) {

        body, err := getRequestBody(func() {})

        assert.Nil(t, body)
        assert.Equal(t, err.Error(), "unable to marshal the request body to json")
    })
```